# Angular - Adding upvote button inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im having a problem trying to add an upvote button to an element in a list created with an ng-repeat. The list is deal in deals. The section uses the deal.controller  and data-ng-init="find()".

The deal.controller has the funtion

```
   // Find a list of Deals

    $scope.find = function() {

        $scope.deals = Deals.query();

    };
```

The button on each element uses ng-click

```
    <button ng-click="upVote(deal._id)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger
 vote-up-button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></i> Hot</button>
```

which calls the upvote function

```
    // upVoteDeal

    $scope.upVote = function (id) {

        $scope.deal.votes = $scope.deal.votes+1;

        var deal = $scope.deal;

        deal.$update(function() {
            $location.path('deals/' + deal._id);
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });


    };
```

The problem i have is it is saying that `$scope.deal.votes = $scope.deal.votes+1;`is wrong.

Its coming back with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'votes' of undefined`

Comment: I think you'd have to define `$scope.deal.votes` outside the `$scope.upvote` function like this: `$scope.deal  = { votes :  '' }`

Comment: I could be wrong but that seems to make a whole new deal rather than use the deal from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in the whole object, not just it's id.

```
 <button ng-click="upVote(deal)">
```

Now you have everything you need right inside the function in controller

```
$scope.upVote = function(deal) {

    deal.votes++;
    deal.$update(function() {
        $location.path('deals/' + deal._id);
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        // rollback votes on fail also
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
    });
}
```

Comment: Nearly spot on but seems to refresh and say forbidden. Something slightly wrong? edit - wait 1 second. i think its the database.

Comment: Beautiful Thank you. Forbidden was my Mongodb instance was stopped. That really is a huge help. I just changed it slightly to not redirect to the view page.